# Configure zsh to use tab autocompletion when in the middle of a word (ignore chars after the cursor) like in bash

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

In bash (`\bash --noprofile --norc`) when the caret/carriage/cursor (`|`) is in the middle of a word (`l|!@#asdf`) you can double Tab to show suggestions (`ls` for this example) for the word before the caret (`l`). But in zsh (`\zsh -f`) it simply doesn't work — you have to have a space after the caret to autocomplete the word before the caret (`l| !@#asdf`).

This is one of a few things that bash is better at. Could anyone tell me if there's a setting in zsh to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a closer equivalent to bash's completion behaviour in that regard is to use the `expand-or-complete-prefix` widget instead of the default `expand-or-complete` (or `complete-word` if the `_expand` completer is enabled)

```
bindkey '^I' expand-or-complete-prefix
```

Otherwise, you can configure the default one to use the `_prefix` completer if the current word can't be completed but the part of it left of the cursor can:

As a minimum, add:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _prefix
set -o completeinword
```

Before

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

In your `~/.zshrc`.

Easiest is to use `compinstall` to tune completion to your taste. Having *only* those and not benefiting from all the great features of zsh completion would be a waste. Run:

```
autoload compinstall
compinstall
```

Running `compinstall` is also offered as an option by `zsh-newuser-install` which should be invoked the first time you invoke `zsh` without already having a `~/.zshrc`.

You'll want to enable the `_prefix` completer in there. You'll still need to add `set -o completeinword` by hand as it's not currently done by `compinstall`. There's actually a:

> ```
> # TODO: _prefix completer should make sure completeinword is set.
> ```

line in that `compinstall` function.

See [`info zsh _prefix`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fprefix) for details.

Comment: I specifically wrote `\zsh -f` to show that all the aliases and configurations are disabled (to compare bare bash vs zsh). So I do have a lot of stuff configured, and I'm trying not to waste anything that I can benefit from.

Comment: After pressing Tab twice to autocomplete the word before caret (using your setup), which does work, I can't put a space or more specifically I can't stay at the end of autocompleted command. When pressing Enter or Space it jumps to the end of `<completed command>+<jibberish> `. How can I stay in between these parts after selecting a suggested command?

Comment: @Andrew15_5, see edit.

Comment: Great, thank you! I ended up with `bindkey '\t' expand-or-complete-prefix` instead of `'^I'` (as to not introduce a new keybinding, which basically does the same thing).

Comment: @Andrew15_5, `^I` and `\t` are two representations of the TAB character recognised by `bindkey`.

Comment: How strange... Ok. Someone said that it's because of vi mode, but in emacs mode `^I` works too.