# Don't jump to the end of the word after inword (completeinword) completion in zsh

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I've been able to turn on autocompletion when the cursor is in the word: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736909/556055

But the whole point was that I can accept an autocompletion and resume typing stuff in the word/in the same place. But instead, the cursor jumps to the end of the entire word + 1 space after that, when I'm pressing spacebar or Enter key. Can I change this behavior?

P.S. The reference behavior is bash's (with no config).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now the answer was updated, and this issue was addressed too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736909/556055

Basically, you can add:

```bash
bindkey '^I' expand-or-complete-prefix
```

or this:

```bash
bindkey '\t' expand-or-complete-prefix
```

Basically, it's the same thing (Tab) but written differently.